# What is the meaning of <T> in the Material Drag and Drop API references?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

An example, what createDrag returns below.

[image: From Material CDK Drag and Drop API docs]

Comment: A generic type.

Comment: It will return a **DragRef** type of object. <T> = type.

Answer (score 1):

'T' is going to be a type declared at run-time instead of compile time. The T variable could be any non-declared variable (I couldn't find a reference, but I would assume any valid set of characters that could be used for a variable names). Similarly in c#, if the type T represents is not a value type but a more complex type (class) or interface, it could be named/declared as TVehicle or TAnimal to help denote a valid type for future programmers (and could be considered best practice because just T is not intuitive). I prefer TSomething because I know that uppercase T means a generic type. WSometing or ASomething is also valid, but I just don't prefer it. (Microsofts APIs are almost always TContext or TEntity for example).

Answer (score 1):

The generic `T` parameter of `DragRef<T>` refers to the type of `DragRef.data`. This is a field with user-defined semantics and can hold any data you want.

As an example, you can listen to the `DragRef.cdkDragStarted` observable and attach data when you begin dragging. When you release, `DragRef.cdkDragReleased` emits and you can refer back to the same data.